# Jade with Fluidtypo3 (custom syntax)

Tags: gulp, pug, fluid

I am developing [Typo3](http://typo3.org/) websites using [Fluidtypo3](https://fluidtypo3.org/).

Now as fluid has its own syntax with custom elements like:

```
<flux:field.inline.fal name="image" label="Image" allowedExtensions="gif,jpg,jpeg,png" maxItems="1" />
```

I am running into a conflict, when I want to work with jade, because when I convert this html into jade it looks like:

```
flux:field.inline.fal(name="image" label="Image" allowedExtensions="gif,jpg,jpeg,png" maxItems="1")
```

which will be converted by jade to:

```
<flux:field name="image" label="Image" allowedExtensions="gif,jpg,jpeg,png" maxItems="1" class="inline fal"></flux:field>
```

As you can see jade parses the dots from `flux:field.inline.fal` as classes.

My question is, if I it's possible to extend jade to ignore all dots on specific elements like: `flux:*`. If not, then it's possible to escape that dots, so that they will be appended to the elements decleration.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for my problem:

```
#{'flux:field.inline.fal'}
```

will be converted to:

```
<flux:field.inline.fal>
```

And if you want to add classes just put them after the closing bracket:

```
#{'flux:field.inline.fal'}.myClass
```

I hope that will help anyone who runs into the same problem.